# Como desativar script Jquery, em dispositivos mobiles? É possivel?

Tags: jquery

Simplesmente estou querendo desativar meu script Jquery, para não executar em dispositivos menores que 768px, é possivel?

Comment: Pode fazer o contrário, não acha melhor? Carregar o jQuery somente se o usuário não estiver acessando a página por meio de um dispositivo mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar uma condição se a largura da tela for maior que 768, execute o script, caso contrário nada será executado.

```
if ($(window).width() > 768) {
  //Codigo
}
```

Comment: Obrigado resolveu meu problema! :D

Comment: Mas vai usar jQuery para fazer essa verificação? De que adianta? O script já vai ter sido carregado.

Comment: Se a resposta foi de ajuda não se esqueça de avaliá-la para ajudar outros usuários também ;)